# Asp.net single threaded page requests

Tags: asp.net

how to handle multiple http requests from a single client such that it is handled by single Asp.net thread. When PageAsyncTask or TPL is not an option as it does create a new thread. Code snipet will be of great help.

Comment: That's a bad idea.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i've to retain ASP.net thread for some reasons

Comment: That is probably not possible.  _What are you trying to accomplish?_

Comment: Providing potential answerers with more detail about your specific situation would allow them to either answer your question directly, or suggest an alternate course of action that could yield your intended result.

Answer (score 1):

Each separate HTTP request will be executed on a potentially separate thread.

You have no control over which thread execution of your ASP.Net page is scheduled on.

I do not believe this can be accomplished.

Think about why you are trying to do this.  Do you need to share some information between the various HTTP requests?  If so, consider using a session or a cookie to manage that information.

Comment: it can be any random thread. all i want is not to lose that thread afterwards